# Simplify $\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}{x}}{e^x+x^n}$

Tags: integration, closed-form

I seem to have seen quite a lot of integrals in the form:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{e^x+(1+x^n)}$$

But none of those hold a closed forms (at least to my knowledge)

$$\Large\color\red{\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{e^x+x^n}}$$

Does a closed form exist of this integral? (in terms of $n$)

Comment: we don't even have a closed form formula for the poles and residues of $1/(e^z + z^n)$ for $n \ne 0$

Comment: @user1952009 u can give the poles in terms of Lambert W function.

Comment: *I seem to have seen quite a lot of integrals in this form* - Where ?

Comment: @Lucian I was investigating different ways to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\, dx}{e^x(x^n+1)}$ and this keeps coming in the way.

Comment: @JohnVine: That expression does not possess an elementary closed form even for “nice” values of $n\neq0.$

Comment: I know, I was wondering if the modification I made (not distributing) would make a difference. I miswprded my question @Lucian . Am editing